# AngularJS rendering takes a lot of time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a model that's like this:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "A",
            "id": "2",
            "number": 0,
            "info": "info1",
            "childs": [
                {
                    "type": "B",
                    "id": "21",
                    "number": 0,
                    "info": "info1",
                    "childs": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "A",
            "id": "1",
            "number": 0,
            "info": "info1",
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "type": "A",
            "id": "2",
            "number": 0,
            "childs": [
                {
                    "type": "B",
                    "id": "21",
                    "number": 0,
                    "info": "info1",
                    "childs": [
                        {
                            "type": "C",
                            "id": "211",
                            "number": 0,
                            "info": "info1",
                            "childs": [
                                {
                                    "type": "B",
                                    "id": "2111",
                                    "info": "info1",
                                    "number": 0
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

that is rendered in the page via 4 nested `ng-repeat`. The property `number` is changed via an `input="number"`, one for each row. The info value is changed by a `selectbox`
The structure is like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

    <input type="number" ng-model="item.number" />
    <select ng-model="item.info">
    </select>

    <div ng-repeat="child in items.child">

        <input type="number" ng-model="child.number" />
        <select ng-model="child.info">
        </select>

        <div ng-repeat="child2 in child.child">

            <input type="number" ng-model="child2.number" />
            <select ng-model="child2.info">
            </select>

            <div ng-repeat="child3 in child2.child">

                <input type="number" ng-model="child3.number" />
                <select ng-model="child3.info">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Well that's not exactly how's the actual webapp but it's enough for you. Anyway, if I change the value of an `input="number"`, the rendering process takes like 1500ms to complete. The same (but the rendering is a little bit faster) happens when I change the `selectbox` selected option.
When I change the value I just need to update the property of the item in the model. Why does angular render all over again?
What can I do?
Keep in mind that usually the model contains around 10/15 items with 5 to 20 child each.

*PS: Weird thing, when I change the input value clicking on the spinners (the default ones that appear when I use Chrome), the number is incremented or decremented by 2, and not 1.*

EDIT: Still haven't solved this problem. When I have too many items to display in the screen, all the rendering process is too slow with four nested ng-repeat. Anyone has an alternative solution for display my model in the page and modify the values without losing 2s on rendering? I can't use pagination or infinite scrolling.

Comment: I've tried to use your code on a jsfiddle (here: http://jsfiddle.net/ggalmazor/BLAHv/9/) and I can't reproduce the delay you're pointing out. Could you provide a JSFiddle or modify mine with a working example that experiences the delay?

Comment: Also, you could try to search for other common sources for delays and processing time like dead event listeners, excessive use of $watch statements, etc.

Comment: You can't reproduce the delay couse the actual app is much more complex and wide than what I posted here. I can't copy and paste the whole project. That's the structure of the part of the program that's slow.

Comment: It's really hard to guess then. Have you actually determined that there is a 1500ms rendering of the information? Are there other factors that can produce such delay? Maybe there is a slow ajax call, maybe you're performing heavy transformations on the data before using it in the ng-repeat...

Comment: In my example, which is free from data transformation or slow ajax calls, I can prove that the rendering of that particular block of html with that particular set of information is not producing any delay at all...

Comment: I used batarang and analyzed the page. The rendering take 1,5s even if I only change the value of an input box. Ajax call are performed but only while the page is loading. The only trasformation I do when I change the input value is change the value in the corresponding item.number. I dont think its heavy

Comment: I've improved a little my jdfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ggalmazor/BLAHv/17/ still not seeing any rendering delay or the x2 increment on the input you mentioned. Maybe you can play with the fiddle a little bit to search for the cause of the problem...

Comment: Another weird thing is that in another section of the webapp, where I have the same structure but with only 3 nested ng-repeat, the page works very well, fast as always..

Comment: I'm doing some testing and I saw that the more child I have the more slow the page become. With only 3 child the code works properly...

Comment: then your problem is not reproducible if you cant isolate it.

Comment: When I change the value angular render all over again. If I have a lot of child it takes a lot of time. But why. I change the value on the input > the value is written on the model > the value is displaied on the screen...that's it. Why all the model is rendered again?